# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker From ECR Error "No Docker image specified in Dockerrun.aws.json"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ecr

I'm attempting to deploy a docker image from AWS ECR to Elastic Beanstalk. I've set up all required permissions for Elastic Beanstalk to both S3 and ECR. Communication between these services seems fine, however I get the following errors when attempting to fire up an Elastic Beanstalk environment:

1. `No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.`
2. `[Instance: i-01cf0bac1863e4eda] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.`

I'm uploading a single `Dockerrun.aws.json` which points to the image on ECR. Below is my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "containerDefinitions": {
    "Name": "***.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/***:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

The docker image does exist on ECR at the location specified in the `containerDefinitions` `Name` field.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `containerDefinitions` is not applicable in this situation. I'm not sure where I found it (maybe from a dockerrun sample somewhere). The actual property name is as below:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "***.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/***:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

Comment: I continue to get the same error as before with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. Had the same problem. It was because of Dockerfile encoding. Use UTF-8 instead of UTF-8-BOM. More details here:
https://github.com/verygood-ops/eb_docker/blob/master/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh#L58

```
    FROM_IMAGE=`cat Dockerfile | grep -i ^FROM | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed $'s/\r//'`
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error when trying to use `AWSEBDockerrunVersion 1` schema  on an environment running "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux **2**" as the platform. The error message gives nothing away.

Creating a new environment as "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux" and redeploying my original `Dockerrun.aws.json` solved the issue for me. You could also migrate your `Dockerrun.aws.json` to the version 2 schema.

Comment: "Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux"  is depreciated, any other option to fix it?